# Downloading library on button click in QGIS plugin

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, library

I am building a plugin in QGIS 3.24 using Python. I want to create a button in the plugin which will in turn download the dependencies such as Pandas, NumPy, GeoPandas, Networkx etc. in the system if its not available.

Is it possible with Python?

Comment: Where do you want to install these libraries? a separate virtual environment, QGIS Python environment i.e. `py3_env`, Anaconda environment, or directly in the system ?

Comment: QGIS python env or virtual env

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap `import package` line in `try-except`. If it throws `ModuleNorFoundError`, then install the package.

```
import subprocess

try:
    import numpy
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', 'numpy'])
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to install the library in the virtual environment I have created in vs code using Python? @Kadir Şahbaz

Comment: This is a different question which should be another post. For a quick solution, I guess, when you run VsCode inside a virtual environment or you switch your Python interpreter to point to the one within your venv, pip installs packages into virtual environment. I have not tried so far.

Comment: okay , fine i will check it out